# Word 2019 - Footnote Columns issue

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2019

On the left is an older version of the same file. We updated a completely different section of the document, but for some reason the footnote on the olderfile stays in one column floating so the right column can goto the bottom of the page... while on the new file on the right, it forces the footnotes to balance across the two columns.

[file comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKz6k.png)

I want the file on the right, to look like the file on the left.

I tried making the footnotes 1 column, instead of matched to rest of document... but then it spans the bottom, so doesn't solve the problem.

I'm baffled?
I'm not even sure why it changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent 3 hours with Microsoft's online support and have come to the conclusion (with the tech) that the newest version of Word, 2019, added new functionality so that the footnotes section could be independently set to any number of columns, or to match the number of columns of the section it is in. Admitedly this allows for greater control of the footnotes section, as you can now have a footnote section span the entire page, while the content is in multiple columns... or vice versa.
In doing so, however, they have removed, or perhaps not yet added the ability to force the footnotes into the column in which they reference above (assuming the number of columns of content matches the number of columns of footnotes).

TLDR. Word 2019 will not allow the footnote elements to stay in one column only, nor will it allow the footnotes to "float" in one column. If you want what i wanted, you'll need to use an old version and maintain compatibility when saving.

Comment: I don't know about Word 2019, but in Word 2016, you can avoid having to "use an old version" by saving your current `docx` file as `.doc`, then saving it as `.docx` again while (as you correctly indicate) maintaining compatibility mode. Thanks for the hint!